# Async Rsync Dired error on tramp file not found

Tags: dired, tramp, async

I am trying to copy files from one directory on a remote computer to another directory on the same remote computer.

Using Dired I can open up the two directories, mark the files I want to copy and press C. This works but is very slow and holds up the computer.

So I found https://truongtx.me/tmtxt-dired-async.html however this only seems to work for copying files on my local computer. If I try and mark and copy a file on a remote computer I get :

`rsync change dir "/sourcepath/file1" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/destpath/" failed:  No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(695) [Receiver=3.1.2]`

The window only displays for a few seconds before disappearing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Contact the author of tmtxt-dired-async.el. Ask how to do it or whether it can be done.

Comment: Likely you can't with current Tramp. There exists a branch in Emacs' git repository to run Tramp asynchronously. This work is stalled due to problems with Emacs' implementation of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking at [dired-rsync](https://melpa.org/#/dired-rsync) which is available from MELPA.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author.